# Remove key and/or array elements from jsonb values

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

We have a `jsonb` of column `meta` in table `metaTable`:

```
{
 "records": {
    record1: {
        "GUID-1": {
           values: ["GUID-value-1", "GUID-value-2", "GUID-value-3"],
           type: "..."
        },
        "GUID-2": {
           values: ["GUID-value-4", "GUID-value-5"],
           type: "..."
        },
        "GUID-3": {
           values: ["GUID-value-6"],
           type: "..."
        },
        "GUID-4": {
           values: ["GUID-value-7"],
           type: "..."
        }
    }
 },
 "miscellaneous": {
    .....
 }
}
```

The `"GUID-1"`, `"GUID-2"`, `"GUID-3"`, and `"GUID-4"` are key.

The  `"GUID-value-1"`, `"GUID-value-2"`, `"GUID-value-3"`, `"GUID-value-4"`, `"GUID-value-5"`, `"GUID-value-6"`, and `"GUID-value-7"` are values.

*Both of keys and values are unique.*

We are trying to remove keys and/or nested array elements from the JSON document that are listed in a given array. For example:

`["GUID-3", "GUID-value-4", "GUID-value-1", "GUID-value-2", "GUID-value-3", "GUID-value-7", "GUID-4", "random-GUID1", "random-GUID2"]`

Expected result:

```
{
 "records": {
    record1: {
        "GUID-2": {
           values: ["GUID-value-5"],
           type: "..."
        }
    }
 },
 "miscellaneous": {
    .....
 }
}
```

Note 1: `"GUID-1"` is removed because the array `"values"` is empty.
Note 2: This SQL will apply to every row.

I have tried:

```
update metaTable
set "meta" = 
json_set("meta", '{records, record1, GUID-1, values}', ("meta" -> 'records' -> 'record1' -> 'GUID-1' -> values) - '{GUID-value-1, GUID-value-2", GUID-value-3}'::text[])
```

This only works if I already know that `GUID-`1 is the key, and `GUID-value-1, GUID-value-2, and GUID-value-3` are values.

Is there any generic way to do it within 1 SQL query without figuring out the role of each GUID beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution:

```sql
SELECT t.id, jsonb_pretty(jsonb_set(meta, '{records,record1}', r.upd_rec))
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN (
   SELECT '{GUID-3,GUID-value-4,GUID-value-1,GUID-value-2,GUID-value-3,GUID-value-7,GUID-4,random-GUID1,random-GUID2}'::text[]  -- input here!
   ) d(del_arr)
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT jsonb_object_agg(r.k, jsonb_set(r.v, '{values}', (r.v -> 'values') - d.del_arr))          
   FROM   jsonb_each(t.meta #> '{records,record1}') r(k,v)
   WHERE  r.k <> ALL (d.del_arr)
   AND   (r.v -> 'values') - d.del_arr <> jsonb '[]'
   ) r(upd_rec)
ORDER  BY t.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZE4Y_mhM)

You can build your `UPDATE` from it. There is a lot to explain. And it can be optimized further.

But I feel this is too specific to be useful to the general public. Stuff for paid consulting, really.